# Lambda expression on array property

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, lambda, linq-to-objects

Use-case:
PHP symfony project which has to communicate with a C# back-end with Mongo. In the PHP front-end it is possible to make a query to get data from Mongo. This query is send via an API (XML). The C# back-end deserializes this XML to get the objects. Then I want to execute an Linq-to-objects query (which is the query send via the API) on a collection in my memory. So I wanted to make my own "LinqBuilder" so I can query the objects and return them to my PHP front-end.

I have the following object:

```
public class MongoDoc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Kind { get; set; }
    public BsonDocument Data { get; set; }
}
```

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
var list = source.Where(x => x.Data["Identifier"] == "H7PXXK").ToList(); // source is collection of MongoDoc objects
```

The code line above is what I want to build with expressions because it has to be dynamic. What I did achieve is to query the "Kind" property of my MongoDoc object as follow:

```
ParameterExpression _expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MongoDoc), "x");    
expression = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(_expr, "Kind"), 
    Expression.Constant("KindValue")
);
```

This will produce the following lamdba:

```
x => (x.Kind == "KindValue")
```

That is correct, but now I need to get the property Identifier in the BsonDocument property Data. Normally it would be something like above: `x => x.Data["Identifier"] == "Value"`. This is exactly what my problem is. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

think it should be something like that.

```
var _expr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MongoDoc), "x");

//x.Data
Expression member = Expression.PropertyOrField(_expr, "Data");

//x.Data["Identifier"]
member = Expression.Property(member, "Item", new Expression[]{Expression.Constant("Identifier")}); 

//x.Data["Identifier"] == "H7PXXK"
member = Expression.Equal(member, Expression.Constant((BsonValue)"H7PXXK"));
```

EDIT :

from your comment, it should be

```
//x.Data["MoreData"]
member = Expression.Property(member, "Item", new Expression[]{Expression.Constant("MoreData")}); 
//x.Data["MoreData"]["Identifier"]
member = Expression.Property(member, "Item", new Expression[]{Expression.Constant("Identifier")});
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. I just had to add a cast to BsonValue because x.Data["Identifier"] is of type BsonValue. Else you would get this exception: "The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue' and 'System.String'."

Comment: Next up is what if the Data property has another BsonDocument as property so you need something like x.Data["MoreData"]["Identifier"]

Comment: @DeluxZ for the next up, see edit (casts also missing).